# Compile and run C++ code

Tags: bash

I have created this bash script for Compile And Run c++ code, car++.sh.
As I'm new to bash scripting, I'm not sure about good bash programming practices.

Please review it to see if you could find any anomaly.

```
#!/bin/bash

found=false;
output=;
o_is_set=false;

#retrieve output_filename from arguments as provided by user
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [ "$o_is_set" = true ]
    then
        output="$arg";
        found=true;
        break;
    fi

    if [[ $arg == -o ]]
    then
        o_is_set=true;
    fi
done

#else retrieve from file name of first .cpp or .c++ file specified
if [ "$found" = false ]
then
    for file in "$@"
    do
        ext=$(echo $file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]');

        if [[ $ext == *.cpp ]]
        then
            output=$(basename "$file" ".cpp");
            found=true;
            break;
        fi

        if [[ $ext == *.c++ ]]
        then
            output=$(basename "$file" ".c++");
            found=true;
            break;
        fi
    done
fi

#else retrieve from first .c file specified
if [ "$found" = false ]
then
    for file in "$@"
    do
        ext=$(echo $file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]');

        if [[ $ext == *.c ]]
        then
            output=$(basename "$file" ".c");
            found=true;
            break;
        fi
    done
fi

#output file name is not specified by user and there is no C++ or C file,
#lets see what g++ says about it
if [ "$found" = false ]
then
echo;
    g++ -Wall -std=c++11 "$@";
    exit "$?";
fi

run="./$output";

g++ -Wall -o "$output" -std=c++11 "$@" && $run;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this instead of using a build system such as CMake?

Comment: @syb0rg sometimes if I'm learning a new concept in C++, I want to just compile and run the C++ code fast.

Comment: CMake is an incredibly fast and dynamic way to generate a Makefile so that you can compile and run your code fast.  Another option worth looking into is an IDE if you're looking for rapid development for new concepts.

Comment: @syb0rg Sorry, I got busy in something.  
I skimmed through the tutorial of [CMake] (http://mathnathan.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-cmake/). Using it requires creating CMakeLists.txt, then calling cmake, then make, then _executable_ generated. I wouldn't want to go through that for compiling few (< 20) lines of code. However, I think it would be useful while creating a relatively big project which has 2 or more files.

Comment: True, but keep in mind that it is also more portable.  Your script won't work on Windows, for example.

Comment: @syb0rg On windows, one can do -> `cl code.cpp` and `code` through command line. cl comes with Visual Studio. Perhaps, with VSC++ Express which is freely available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good start, but I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Try to reduce the scope of variables

The variables `o_is_set` and `found` are essentially global variables, but don't need to be.  Instead, the code might be structured as a series of functions, reducing the linkage within the code.

### Use standard option parsing

One could use `getopts` for parsing command line options, or plain old `bash` for that.  For example, consider this code for parsing a `-o` option with its corresponding argument:

```
while [[ $# > 1 ]]
    do
        opt="$1"
        case $opt in 
            -o)
            OUTPUT="$2"
            shift
            ;;
            *)
                # ignore unknown option
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
```

### Use `make` instead

The basic operation of this file is to create an executable from either a `.cpp` or `.c` file using the `gcc` compiler and then running the resulting executable.  One can do essentially the same thing with a single line:

```
#!/bin/bash 
make $1 && ./$1
```

For example, if we have `nuts.c` in the current working directory and the file above is called `car` we can execute `./car nuts` and `make` will run, find the `nuts.c` file, create an executable `nuts` and then run it.