# Bash - Compile C++ File Function

Tags: c++, bash

As I am starting to be tired of reverse-searching in history for the C++ compile command, which I'm using - [details on my flags are written here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360300/270735), I defined the following `.bash_aliases` function:

```
function compile-cpp {

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    {
        echo "Need a file to compile as argument."
    }
    else
    {
        # extract file name from path
        filename=$(basename "$1")

        # cut the extension
        filename="${filename%.*}"

        # compile
        g++ $1 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -o "$filename"
    }
    fi

}
```

The goal was to take one `cpp` file as argument and compile it under the same name as the source's.

So, e.g. when I call:

```
compile-cpp delete.cpp
```

I expect it to output a file named as:

```
delete
```

In the same directory.

No problems, *so far*, detected by me, but as I am a C++ beginner, I can't know for sure, if this command will *more or less* always work.

Note: I don't wish to use a `Makefile` yet. The *projects* and various *examples* I work with are so little and there's so many of them, I believe it would be counterproductive.

I found the following question, probably trying to achieve somewhat similar thing:

[Compile and run C++ code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/85941/104270)

But since I have different demands, looking at his code, I believe it is not its duplicate, in spite of having close to the same titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just go:

```
export CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors
```

Then at any point you want to compile:

```
make plop.cpp
```

This will build the executable `plop`. Use the `CXXFLAGS` and does **NOT** need a makefile.

If you want to keep your function, I would allow people to override the defaults using the environment:

```
function compile-cpp {

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    {
        echo "Need a file to compile as argument."
    }
    else
    {
        # extract file name from path
        filename=$(basename "$1")

        # cut the extension
        filename="${filename%.*}"

        # compile
        if [ -z "${VERBOSE}" ]
        then
        {
            # Normally just want to see the file that is being compiled.
            echo ${CXX:-g++} $1 -o ${filename}
        }
        else
        {
            # But if things are going wrong then you want to see the full command LINE.
            echo ${CXX:-g++} $1 ${CXXFLAGS:-'-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors'} -o "$filename"
        }
        fi
        ${CXX:-g++} $1 ${CXXFLAGS:-'-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors'} -o "$filename"
    }
    fi

}
```

Here:

```
${CXX:-g++} means if the environment variable is empty or null use `g++`
            otherwise use the value of `${CXX}`.

Same for the `${CXXFLAGS}`
```

I would prefer using the `make` technique, as this provides you all the facilities of Make in addition to the compiler (so it checks file date stamps) and other stuff.

```
## Use the fortran compiler for shits and giggles
CXX=fortran compile-cpp plop.cpp
VERBOSE=1 compile-cpp plop.cpp
```

Comment: A very complete answer!  One minor improvement: I suggest redirecting the error message to stderr (`>&2`).  I'm not sure about the verbose logging - stdout or stderr?  Perhaps worth seeing what `set -x` does (and perhaps simply using `set -x` as the `else` branch - but it would need to be restored, so perhaps not worth it).